# IF and ELSE statement in spark sql expression

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am looking to run a sql expression that checks for the next event that is either 'DELIVERED' or 'ORDER-CANCELED' and return a different result depending on which is first.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([["ORDER", "2009-11-23", "1"], ["DELIVERED", "2009-12-17", "1"], ["ORDER-CANCELED", "2009-11-25", "1"], ["ORDER", "2009-12-03", "1"]]).toDF("EVENT", "DATE", "ID")
    
+--------------+----------+---+
|         EVENT|      DATE| ID|
+--------------+----------+---+
|         ORDER|2009-11-23|  1|
|ORDER-CANCELED|2009-11-25|  1|
|         ORDER|2009-12-03|  1|
|     DELIVERED|2009-12-17|  1|
+--------------+----------+---+
```

I have written a statement that works for just an DELIVERED event using this code:

```
df = df.withColumn("NEXT", f.expr("""
    case when EVENT = 'ORDER' then 
        first(if(EVENT in ('DELIVERED'), 'SUCCESS', null), True)
        over (Partition By ID ORDER BY ID, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
    else null end
    """))
```

This works but I don't know how to add in a second condition for the else statement of 'ORDER-CANCELED'.

```
df = df.withColumn("NEXT", f.expr("""
    case when EVENT = 'ORDER' then 
        first(if(EVENT in ('DELIVERED'), 'SUCCESS', null) 
        **elseif(EVENT in ('ORDER-CANCELED'), 'CANCELED'), True)**
        over (Partition By ID ORDER BY ID, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
    else null end
    """))
```

Comment: why don't you just use a `case when` everywhere ? that's the sql "if then" statement. Do not mix syntaxes

Answer (score 0):

something like this maybe ?

```py
df = df.withColumn(
    "NEXT", 
    f.expr("""
        case when EVENT = 'ORDER' then 
            first(
                case when EVENT in ('DELIVERED') then 
                    'SUCCESS'
                     when EVENT in ('ORDER-CANCELED') then 
                    'CANCELED'
                     else
                    NULL
                end
            ) over (Partition By ID ORDER BY ID, DATE ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) 
            else NULL
        end
    """))
```